# Compute weighted 2d histogram given shifts from center

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, histogram

I have multiple 2D numpy arrays (image data of a bright object, each of size 600x600), and I ran a cross-correlation on each of the individual images vs. a stacked composite image using `skimage.feature.register_translation` to obtain the relative subpixel shifts of each image's centroid with respect to the centroid of the composite image. I'd now like to create a weighted 2d histogram of all my individual image data, using the relative shifts of each in order to have all of them exactly centered. But I'm confused on how to do this. My code so far is below (after finding the shifts):

```
import numpy as np

data = #individual image data; this is an array of multiple 2D (600x600) arrays

# Shifts in x and y (each are same length as 'data')
dx = np.array([0.346, 0.23, 0.113, ...])
dy = np.array([-0.416, -0.298, 0.275, ...])

# Bins
bins = np.arange(-300, 300, 1)

# Weighted histogram
h, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(dx.ravel(), dy.ravel(), bins=bins, weights=data.ravel())
```

This isn't getting me anywhere though -- I think my `weights` parameters is wrong (I think there should be just one weight per image, instead of the whole image?), but don't know what else I would put for it. The images are of different bright sources, so I can't just assume they all have the same widths either. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you try `data[0].ravel()` as weights? Else, please provide some more `data`

Comment: Each entry in `data` is a 600x600 array so it might be a little much for me to paste those here. Why `data[0]`, though? That would just be the data for my first image.